# Express the distance from a point $(x,y)$ on the graph of $x+y=1$ to the point $(2,3)$ as a function of $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having problems understanding how to extract this information into a formula.

> express the distance from a point $(x,y)$ on the graph of $x+y=1$ to the point $(2,3)$ as a function of $x$

(note, i do have have the answer to the question, my question is on how to extract the information)

Any help would be much appreciated, Cheers!

Comment: You are given one point and the equation $y = 1 - x$. You can find the distance between two points via $\sqrt{(p_2)^2 + (p_1)^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying the [distance formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_formula#Geometry) to the points $(x,y)$ and $(2,3)$, we obtain:
$$
d(x) = \sqrt{(x - 2)^2 + (y - 3)^2}
$$
But since $(x,y)$ lies on the graph of $x + y = 1$, we know that $y = 1 - x$. Substituting, we get that:
\begin{align*}
d(x) &= \sqrt{(x - 2)^2 + ((1 - x) - 3)^2} \\
&= \sqrt{(x - 2)^2 + (-x - 2)^2} \\
&= \sqrt{(x^2 - 4x + 4) + (x^2 + 4x + 4)} \\
&= \sqrt{2x^2 + 8} \\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Since you want a function of $x$, you should write $y=1-x$ for the equation of the graph. Now, the distance from *any* point $(x,y)$ to $(2,3)$ is given by the formula:
$$\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2}$$
But you want a formula for the distance from a point of the graph to $(2,3)$. Since the coordinates of every point of the graph satisfy the equation $y=1-x$, you should substitute this value of $y$ into the formula:
$$\sqrt{(x-2)^2+[(1-x)-3]^2}$$